# javascript source code reuse

Tags: javascript

I am not familiar with javascript and I have had some exposure to java but I found a web application that fits the goals of my app perfectly. The owner has provided the source by viewing the source in the html and I was wondering how hard it would be to reuse the code to deploy a similar app.

Comment: Java has **nothing** to do with Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks: I wish they'd just change the name already.  Better yet - change the name of Java ;-)

Comment: It's hard to change the name of an entire island :S specially when it's in indonesia

Comment: SLaks: vbNewbie didn't say it did, but was merely providing a reference for what he knew.  Replace "java" with "C#" there if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is your question, but:

- "*I have had some exposure to java"*:  Javascript has nothing to do with java except the name
- "*The owner has provided the source by viewing the source in the html*": Javascript is always visible from the client side, so it might not be intention of the owner to share it into other projects
- Reusing dificulty will depend on how good can you read his code and if it is accessing any server via ajax to fetch code or if it is generating code on the fly.

Comment: The web app is hosted on the owners server and he has made available the script available in the page source; however it is the results that he gets that interest me and I would like to use his script and divert the results to my app or database. I know mozilla has firebug available which allows one to look at the script and results but that would require manually extracting the results. Hope this made sense. Keep in mind that I do have less than one year experience in programming.